# Hundreds of pictures in UIImage array - memory leak

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage

I am working on an app which creates frames out of the recorded video:

```
var videoFrames:[UIImage] = [UIImage]()
func loadImages(){
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: capturedFrames, completionHandler: {requestedTime, image, actualTime, result, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let image = image {
                self.videoFrames.append(UIImage(cgImage: image))                }
        }
    })
}
```

Codes works fine for up to +/- 300 images loaded.
When there's more, app is Terminated due to memory issue - I am fairly new to swift - how can I debug it further?

Is there any better way to store so many images? Will splitting into couple arrays fix the issue?

My goal is to store thousands of photos (up to 1920x1080) efficiently - maybe you can recommend some better method?

Comment: Use SDImage it will create cache of memory

Comment: Well, if you think about it, storing hundreds of images in memory eventually will result in using up all available memory for sure. I'd suggest you don't store the images in memory at all, but save them to disk immediately and if you need to process them, you should be retrieving them from the disk in batches.

Comment: PINCache or any other cache might be a solution in your situation

Comment: Use KingFisher and set a low memory threshold, forcing the library to fetch the cached images from disk.

Comment: You can't store up to 300 images in memory, I'm surprised it doesn't crash before. Saving them to disk is the right pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Write the image to the disk and Maintain a database with image name and path.

```
    if let image = image {
           let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: image)
           let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: ("__file_path__" + "\(actualTime).png"))
            uiImage.pngData()!.write(to: fileURL)
           //write filepath and image name to database
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding some code of mine, it's an old code that I have in a never published app. It's in objC but the concepts are still valid, the main difference between the other code posted is that the handler takes also in consideration the orientation of the captured video, of course you must give a value to the orientation variable.

```
__block int i = 0;

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){

        if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {

            NSMutableDictionary * metadata = @{}.mutableCopy;
            [metadata setObject:@(recordingOrientation) forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyOrientation];;
            NSString * path = [mainPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image_%.5ld.jpg",(long)i]];
            CFURLRef url = (__bridge_retained CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
            CFMutableDictionaryRef metadataImage = (__bridge_retained CFMutableDictionaryRef) metadata;
            CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, NULL);
            CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, im, metadataImage);
            if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) {
                DLog(@"Failed to write image to %@", path);
            }
            else {
                DLog(@"Writing image to %@", path);

            }

        }
        if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorFailed) {
            //DLog(@"Failed with error: %@ code %d", [error localizedDescription],error.code)
           DLog(@"Failed with error: %@ code %ld for CMTime requested %@ and CMTime actual %@", [error localizedDescription],(long)error.code, CFAutorelease( CMTimeCopyDescription(kCFAllocatorDefault, requestedTime)), CFAutorelease(CMTimeCopyDescription(kCFAllocatorDefault,actualTime)));
            DLog(@"Asset %@",videoAsset);
        }
        if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Canceled");
        }
++i;
}
```